# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ICEfaces rendering required

Tags: jsp, jsf, icefaces

I want to refresh certain DOM elements within my icefaces enhanced page.

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{profileBean.editProfile}">
<f:param name="profileId" value="#{profile.id}" />
<h:outputText value="#{profile.label}" />
<f:ajax event="action" render=":profileEditorForm"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I have

```
<context-param>
<param-name>org.icefaces.render.auto</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in my web.xml and

```
<icecore:config render="true" />
```

in my xhtml file.

The complete error message is

```
Mai 02, 2012 9:28:14 AM com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMContext attachDOMContext
Schwerwiegend: ICEfaces rendering required by icefaces-compat.jar components. Enable    via <icecore:config render="true" />.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ICEfaces rendering required.
at com.icesoft.faces.context.DOMContext.attachDOMContext(DOMContext.java:93)
at     com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.FormRenderer.encodeBegin(FormRenderer.java:62)
```